# Difference in JavaScript Bind method

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between

```
foo.bind(this)(arg1, arg2);
```

and

```
foo.bind(this, arg1, arg2)();
```

Both codes works fine on many sites, but in one site second example gives error due to the fact that `arg2` is `undefined`.

**UPDATE for more complex example**

```
// Create an immediately invoked functional expression to wrap our code
(function () {

    // Define our constructor 
    this.Widget = function (options) {

        this.widgetWrap = null;
        this.widgetHeaderTitle = null;

        //Code removed for clarity

        // Establish our default settings
        this.options = extend({
            formHeaders: ['Заголовок 1', 'Заголовок 2'],
        }, options);

        this.init();

    };

    // Public Methods

    Widget.prototype.init = function () {

        //Code removed for clarity

        contentAnimation.bind(this)(this.widgetHeaderTitle, this.options.formHeaders);

        //Not working on http://healthyclinic.ru/ but working on any other site
        //this.options.formHeaders - Array with several elements. NOT NULL and NOT UNDEFINED
        //contentAnimation.bind(this, this.widgetHeaderTitle, this.options.formHeaders)();

        //Code removed for clarity

    };

    // Private Methods

    function contentAnimation(el, arr) {
        //In this place with second example 'arr' already UNDEFINED
        var self = this;
        var current = 1;
        self.titleAnimationInterval = setInterval(function () {
            el.style.opacity = 0;
            setTimeout(function () {
                el.textContent = arr[current];
                el.style.opacity = 1;
                current = ++current % arr.length;
            }, self.options.transitionDuration);
        }, 4000);
    }

    //Code removed for clarity

}());
```

In the code above, you can see the code in my library. The code works fine on many sites and on the local machine, with the exception of only one site where the second argument becomes `undefined`.

Comment: What site? Please give a specific example  that breaks.

Comment: `foo.bind(this, "x", undefined)();` should be valid. Maybe you could give the whole example showing how it breaks.

Comment: `arg2` was never declared. Because, when I logged function `arguments` in console, it returns array-like object which contains only `arg1`

Comment: So if it is never declared than both should error out

Comment: @epascarello: In strict mode, at least.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but there is no difference either. It must be something else, like a typo (caused by an encoding problem?) or whatever. Btw, why are you using `bind` at all and not `call`?

Comment: How are you calling `Widget()`?

Comment: `new Widget({
            "formHeaders": ["text1", "text2"],
        });`

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no difference in functionality between the two (that `foo` would be able to detect), given that `foo` is a function and `.bind()` is [the built-in function method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).